# test an array against another to see if the positions match, one has the right value in the wrong spot, or a value isn't in the array in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, if-statement, compare

I'm making the game Mastermind in visual basic, and am still fairly new to programming. I am up to the part where I need to test the user's guess against the hidden code, both of which are currently in 2d arrays. The program needs to test whether the user's 4 colour guess has the colours in the correct spot, the correct colours in the wrong spot, or the incorrect colour altogether. It will then randomise this and give the user feedback (green for completely correct, red for completely incorrect & black for partially correct). Currently, I am just using if statements and testing a whole bunch of values for each, but this is one: not efficient, and two: the black will not show, merely giving red if it isn't 100% correct. This is the current code:

```
While i <= 3
        If UserGuessArray(NoofGuesses, i) = HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, i) Then
            UserFeedbackArray(NoofGuesses, i) = "Green"
        ElseIf ((UserGuessArray(NoofGuesses, i) <> HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 0)) AndAlso (UserGuessArray(NoofGuesses, i) <> HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 1)) AndAlso (UserGuessArray(NoofGuesses, i) <> HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 2)) AndAlso (UserGuessArray(NoofGuesses, i) <> HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 3))) Then
            UserFeedbackArray(NoofGuesses, i) = "Red"
        ElseIf UserGuessArray(NoofGuesses, i) = HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 0) And HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 0) <> HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, i) Or HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 1) And HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 1) <> HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, i) Or HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 2) And HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 2) <> HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, i) Or HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 3) And HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, 3) <> HiddenCode(NoofGuesses, i) Then
            UserFeedbackArray(NoofGuesses, i) = "Black"
        End If

        i = i + 1
End While
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly, learn which loop is appropriate in which circumstance.  if you want to do something for the `Integer` values 0 to 3 then you use a `For` loop.  At each index, you first test whether that element in the target array is the same as the same element in the user array.  If not, you then test whether the target array contains the user element at that index at all.  The second test should be one call to `Contains` and there's no need for that second `ElseIf`.  It's basically `If...=...ElseIf...Contains...Else...End If`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I I can't get the Contains statement to work with my array. I've been googling different ways to do it, but nothing has worked. This is what I currently am left with:`ElseIf HiddenCodeArray(0) Contains UserGuessArray(NoofGuesses, i) Then` I've also tried using `HiddenCodeArray.Contains` to no avail but it won't let me use a type as an expression. I know it will seem stupid and obvious to you, but I just can't figure it out! Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code demonstrates what I suggested in my comment above:

> Firstly, learn which loop is appropriate in which circumstance. If you
>   want to do something for the `Integer` values 0 to 3 then you use a `For`
>   loop. At each index, you first test whether that element in the target
>   array is the same as the same element in the user array. If not, you
>   then test whether the target array contains the user element at that
>   index at all. The second test should be one call to `Contains` and
>   there's no need for that second `ElseIf`. It's basically
>   `If...=...ElseIf...Contains...Else...End If`.

```
Dim target = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Dim guess = {1, 5, 2, 8}

For i = 0 To 3
    If target(i) = guess(i) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Value {0} is correct and index {1} is correct.", guess(i), i)
    ElseIf target.Contains(guess(i)) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Value {0} is correct but index {1} is NOT correct.", guess(i), i)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Value {0} is NOT correct and index {1} is NOT correct.", guess(i), i)
    End If
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 picture boxes with a choice of four colors for each. The solution will have 3 different colors in a certain order. The lstAnswer is a List(Of Color) randomly generated. The lstPictures is a list of the PictureBoxes. The player will only be told how many colors are correct and how many are in the correct position. They need to guess again until all colors are in the correct positions.

```
Private Function GetColorMatches() As Integer
        Dim Matches As Integer
        For Each pb As PictureBox In lstPictures
            If lstAnswer.Contains(pb.BackColor) Then
                Matches += 1
            End If
        Next
        Return Matches
    End Function

    Private Function GetPositionsCorrect() As Integer
        Dim correctPosition As Integer
        'Comparing one structure to another does not have "=" relationship
        If PictureBox1.BackColor.Equals(lstAnswer.Item(0)) Then
            correctPosition += 1
        End If
        If PictureBox2.BackColor.Equals(lstAnswer.Item(1)) Then
            correctPosition += 1
        End If
        If PictureBox3.BackColor.Equals(lstAnswer.Item(2)) Then
            correctPosition += 1
        End If
        Return correctPosition
    End Function
```